# Azure Data Factory - Reading JSON Array and Writing to Individual CSV files

Tags: azure, csv, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have many JSON files that lands in my data lake that all have the same format like this:

```
[
  {
    "AzureContainer": "someContainer",
    "AzureFolderName": "someFolder",
    "AzureFilename": "myFilename",
    "Timestamp: "123123213",
    "ItemName": "myItem",
    "Value": 567
  },
  {
    "AzureContainer": "someContainer",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

What I want to do, is to use the information in these items to append to CSV files in my Data Lake (or create them if they don't exist) in the format:

```
[Timestamp],[ItemName],[Value]
[Timestamp],[ItemName],[Value]
....
```

I also need to generate the CSV filename as **ddmmyyyy_[AzureFilename].csv**

What I've done thus far is create a lookup that reads all of the files within my landing blob. I can then extract each of these individual JSON objects. Now, I need to use the information in the JSON object to write to the specified location in my Azure storage account (using AzureContainer, AzureFolderName and AzureFilename), and I need to create a CSV entry using Timestamp, ItemName and Value.

How can I do this? I'm trying to find something that allows me to write to a CSV without having to assign a Source datasource? Thus I want to format my CSV content, and use the Azure parameters to append the CSV file in the specified location.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dataflow` activity and loop in `Foreach` loop to write source **JSON** files to individual **CSV** files.

**JSON Source**:

[image]

Create a source **JSON dataset** and pass the filename dynamically.

[image]

In the **pipeline**, connect the source dataset to the `Get Metadata` activity to get the list of files from the source folder. In **Field list**, select **child items**. This gets all the list of files from the folder.

[image]

**Output of Get Metadata**:

[image]

**Connect output of Get Metadata to Foreach loop**:

In settings, select **Sequential** and in **Items**, add the expression to get the output child items.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems
```

[image]

Add **dataflow activity** inside Foreach loop. Inside dataflow create a parameter to pass sink filename from source.

[image]

Add **source connection** to the dataflow source.

[image]

Create a **sink connection** and add it to the dataflow sink.

[image]

In **sink settings**, select **File name option** as "Output to single file" and add an expression to **generate sink filename in Filename property**.

```
concat(toString(currentDate(),'ddMMyyyy'),"_",replace($dynamicSinkCSV, '.json', '.csv'))
```

[image]

In **mappings**, select only the columns which are required.

[image]

In `Foreach` loop, at **dataflow level settings**, pass the value of Source filename as current item of foreach loop.

[image]

In **parameters**, pass the value of sink file name which is the same as source filename (current item of Foreach loop).

[image]

When you execute the pipeline you can see the loop iterated 2 times as in the source folder there are 2 files.

[image]

**CSV files generated in Sink folder**:

[image]